High consumption of memory in WCF and .NET Framework 4.8
I'm struggling with problem of memory consumption I used a dotMemory and result looks like on the first screen.
Memory consumption
The most amount of memory take System, Castle (3.3.0) and NHibernate (v. 4.1.0)
When I expand information about system I see that the problem is with String, Collection.
In Castle is Default Kernel has the biggest memory and LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy.
I'm looking solution for Castle but I don't know how to resolve issue with System and NHiberante
Do you have any expirenced and anyone could give me some tips because I see that GC work
memory chart
Currently I'm looking any solutions and testing my ideas what I found at Google

Generally speaking, the way to control resources in WCF is through quotas and controllers.
First of all, you can set a timeout, which can save a lot of resources. For example:
ChannelInitializationTimeout : The maximum amount of time to wait for the connection to send a preamble during the initial read.
CloseTimeout : The maximum amount of time to wait for a connection to close before a transfer throws an exception.
IdleTimeout : The maximum amount of time that a pooled connection can remain idle before being shut down.
LeaseTimeout : The maximum lifetime of an active connection that has been pooled. After the specified time has elapsed, the connection is closed as soon as the current request is served.
OpenTimeout : The maximum amount of time to wait for a connection to be established before a transfer throws an exception.
ReceiveTimeout : The maximum amount of time to wait for a read operation to complete before the transfer throws an exception.
SendTimeout : The maximum amount of time to wait for a write operation to complete before a transfer throws an exception.
Secondly, you can also limit the transfer size:
ConnectionBufferSize : The size of the transmit and receive buffers (in bytes) of the underlying transmission. Increasing the buffer size can increase throughput when sending larger messages.
ListenBacklog : The maximum number of connections that a listener can have that haven't been serviced before other connections to that endpoint are denied.
MaxBufferPoolSize : The maximum memory, in bytes, used to form a pool of reusable message buffers is transferred. When the pool is unable to provide a message buffer, the system allocates a new buffer for temporary use.
MaxBufferSize : The maximum size (in bytes) of the buffer used to stream the data.
MaxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint : The maximum number of outgoing connections that can be associated with a specific endpoint.
MaxReceivedMessageSize : The maximum size (in bytes) of the received message, including the header; Beyond this size, the transfer will throw an exception.
As for the controller, ServiceThrottle.MaxConcurrentSessions is an application-level controller that limits the number of concurrent session channel connections to no more than 10 by default. These controls are designed to provide out-of-the-box mitigation against certain types of attacks, or to improve performance metrics such as memory requirements, boot time, and more.

Thanks for the answer, I'll check your proposal and I'll come back with conclusions.
